# CodeIgniter strange issue cannot resolve

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, controller

This is a really annoying and strange issue with CodeIgniter I am trying to use the WHMCS API in a new CodeIgniter project but I keep getting the below errors

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getTickets() on a non-object
```

and

```
Undefined property: Whmcs::$whmcs
```

My controller getTickets function is

```
 function getTickets(){
        if(!empty($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
            $id = $_SESSION['userid'];
            $this->load->model('app/whmcs_model');
            $arr['client'] = $this->whmcs_model->getTickets($id);
            $this->load->view('app/getTickets', $arr);
        }else{
            redirect('/user/login/', 'refresh');
        }
    }
```

My Model getTickets function is

```
function getTickets($id){
        $this->load->library('whmcs');
        return $this->whmcs->getTickets($id);
    }
```

And my WHMCS library getTickets function is

```
public function getTickets($clientid){
        $postfields["action"] = "gettickets";
        $postfields["clientid"] = $clientid;
        $arr = $this->xml($postfields);
        return $arr;
    }
```

This did work before, but I decided to move all WHMCS functions into a single model and controller as the library was already in its own library

Now it just throws the above error, please help it has been two days and I have gotten no where.

The `whmcs.php` controller and `whmcs_model.php` are in a folder app, I know the issue may be in

```
$this->load->library('whmcs');
```

Yet I am unsure why this would be causing the issue as all the code worked before, I have tried running the debug and the following errors appear in this order

```
   Config Class Initialized
   Hooks Class Initialized
   UTF-8 Support Enabled
   Utf8 Class Initialized
   URI Class Initialized
   Router Class Initialized
   Output Class Initialized
   Security Class Initialized
   Global POST, GET and COOKIE data sanitized
   Input Class Initialized
   Language Class Initialized
   Loader Class Initialized
   Helper loaded: url_helper
   Helper loaded: utility_helper
   Database Driver Class Initialized
   Session: Class initialized using 'database' driver.
   Controller Class Initialized
   Model Class Initialized
   Model Class Initialized
   Whmcs class already loaded. Second attempt ignored.
   Undefined property: Whmcs::$whmcs
   Call to a member function getTickets() on a non-object
```

This is as much information as I have gathered and hope someone somewhere can solve this, it has been three days and I have gotten almost nowhere.

I will look forward to your reply

Comment: whmcs library **is not loaded** check if path is wrong or sth, and update question

Comment: I know the WHMCS library is possibly not loading but I have no idea why as that is the correct syntax in codeigniter and the Whmcs.php is located in the root of the library folder, thanks for your response :D also what do you mean by "sth"

Comment: cannot possibly answer why the library is not loaded, without any further info, maybe it requires some other class and not founds it since (relative) paths have been changed

Comment: Strange I rename the library and it worked, does codeigniter cache anything.

Comment: you can answer your own question or i can post my comments as an answer if that helped you

Comment: Nevermind still getting the same issue :(

Comment: does it work if you c\put the library back to original path? if yes it is  a path and/or dependency issue. probably the librray needs some dependencies loaded using relative paths. i guess error handling is custom, try enable full error handling to see all actual errors

Comment: It looks like changing its name did work, but I have no idea why, I wont argue it but I will leave it as is, but it is a really strange issue, thank you @NikosM you have been a great help :D

Comment: i think you should change your logical flow to keep it simple it should be controller --> library->whmcs back to the controller remove the model layer in between and try to avoid same function names in controller ,model and library !!!

Comment: If your original WHMCS_model file is using the same class name as your library file, it could be a class name conflict if both files are loaded.  This wouldn't happen if you follow the naming convention that codeigniter expects... just a thought as I've run into this myself and I noticed your class name was just 'Whmcs'.